# Can't search for a question about "that" and "which"

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed

I knew this question was there: [When is it appropriate to use ‘that’ as opposed to ‘which’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which), but I tried searching for it and couldn't find it. Many usage questions concern function words in English, so it would be nice if we could search for those function words and get reasonable results.

Comment: _this_ is banned too. You cannot search for [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably) with _this that_. That’s a bug, not a feature.

Answer (score 6):

Additionally, the search page itself has a Google search option

https://english.stackexchange.com/search

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/search-options-default-providers.png))</sub>

To get there enter <kbd>enter</kbd> in the search box (eg leave the search terms blank). This page is also linked in the sidebar on every search result page under "search tips".

Comment: Didn't you mean to say *type* `enter` in the search box?

Answer (score 4):

Search now does a much better job of this, which is no longer a stop word - take a peek: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=appropriate+use+of+that+and+which

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the current Stack Exchange search tool filters out [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) prior to indexing the site. The site's search tools are better suited for finding combinations of tags and indexed text. For pure text searches, it is better to use **Google Search** using the `site:` prefix:

> site:english.stackexchange.com <your search query>

#### A Better Search Option

I find the "Related Questions" search *extremely* helpful for finding questions. Click on the `Ask Question` link and type in the title as clearly as you can remember it. The "Related Questions" will often do a much better job at finding the question than the native search tool.

Comment: It seems that on a site concerning questions of English usage, filtering out stop words is going to be ... problematic. Perhaps  a feature request is in order to not drop indexing of stop words that are in quote marks on their own or otherwise indicated as being used as a word *qua* word (such as being italicized on its own), so questions that are *about* stop words can be found.

Comment: @nohat: Creating a separate questions tagged `feature-request` is the best way to log your feature suggestion. The core Q&A engine is the same for all sites but the developers will be evaluating site-specific features to address site-specific issues.

Comment: It was worse on s.o. everytime they tweaked the search it stopped working for single letter terms like 'c'