# What do I do when I see an older duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I have read [Etiquette on duplicate questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381/etiquette-on-duplicate-questions) , but it doesn't give me practical advice about what to do.

I have been trying to track down all questions like "do I need a hyphen in *the one handed sailor?*". I have given them mostly the same tags for better visibility. I have posted a comment "possible duplicate", with a link to the oldest of their kind that I could find. I have added some tags to the slightly different questions and left them alone apart from that. Did I do it right? Should I do something else, like flagging or voting to close? I have heard that moderators can merge questions, but I do not think I can do anything to help with that.

These are the duplicates I have found, oldest first:

- [Should I use " related" or "-related"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/should-i-use-related-or-related) :

> What is the correct use of the term
>   "related?" For example, should I use
>   it like computer related, or is it
>   more proper to use computer-related
>   (where the word "computer" is just
>   part of my example?)
>
> Are the cases where it is used in one
>   form and case in another form, or
>   should it always be used in only one
>   way?

- [Chainsaw-equipped or chainsaw equipped?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4761/chainsaw-equipped-or-chainsaw-equipped) :

> Is it chainsaw-equipped or chainsaw
>   equipped? And with what kind of former
>   words to use "-" properly?

- ["on time" vs. "on-time"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6936/on-time-vs-on-time) :

> I'm in the "on-time" camp when it
>   comes to describing, for example,
>   delivering something by the deadline.
>   Is this the correct usage?
>
> asked by Jason
>
> Are you specifically referring to
>   using it more as an adjective, e.g.
>   *We provide on-time delivery* or also something like *We will deliver it on
>   time?* – Dusty
>
> if you can differentiate between the
>   two, that would be ideal. – Jason

- [Is there a grammar rule behind the hyphen in the phrase 'one-act play'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9549/is-there-a-grammar-rule-behind-the-hyphen-in-the-phrase-one-act-play)

> I noticed that the phrase 'one-act
>   play' always uses a hyphen between
>   'one' and 'act'.
>
> Is there a grammar rule in play here,
>   how does it work?

Comment: Wouldn't http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6359/adjectival-step-by-step/ also be one of those duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention!

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/

It's also fantastic if you can cite the URL of the duplicate, or vote to close it as a dupe of the other question via the "close" item under the post.

More context on duplicates:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/

Comment: Okay, I have flagged them all with a link to this page. I haven't cast close votes yet, because I want to be sure I am using the same idea of "duplicate" as, you know, everyone.