# Declutter EL&U's "Newest" Page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

### Unclutter EL&U before quality drowns

It is my conviction that the site's health would benefit greatly  by removing those very questions that plague the first two or three pages. As soon as an ***unanswered question*** is put *on hold*, deemed *off-topic* *and* the questioner/OP to all intents and purposes has disappeared—a recent phenomenon which I have noted to my great annoyance—then that question should automatically go into "quarantine", i.e. the "unanswered" page; no ifs and buts.

An exception should be made for questions which are accidental *duplicates*. Often a new poster will pose a duplicate question which is worded quite differently from the "original". As I understand it, Stack Exchange [welcomes and loves](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) duplicate questions:

> One thing I want to be clear about, though, is that duplication is not
> necessarily bad. Quite the contrary — some duplication is desirable.
> There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question
> around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different
> words, and the better our coverage, the better odds people can find
> the answer they’re looking for. And isn’t that, really, the whole
> point of this exercise?

> As I’ve mentioned probably ad nauseam at this point, people have the uncanniest knack of asking multiple, nearly identical questions with almost zero words in common.
>
> <sup>Jeff Atwood</sup>

The above snippet was quoted in this meta post below (Oct 29 2010).

> By having closed-but-not-deleted duplicates, we have several
> completely different wordings pointing to the same question. For one,
> that increases our visibility in Google search results. Most
> importantly though, it helps prevent more dupes from being posted in
> the future.
>
> <sup>[RegDwight ♦](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/382/44619)</sup>

So an exception must be made for duplicates, I would even argue that visitors might even visit the dupe question and find them useful.

Furthermore, after one week of inactivity the *off-topic*, *POB*, *unclear*, and *general reference* questions which have not received any answers, and have not been reopened, should be automatically deleted. No ifs, ands or buts. I don't care how many comments a question may have generated, a *closed* question is useless if there is no answer. If the OP is present he or she will try to resuscitate the question, he or she will *care* enough to ask how to improve it, to inquire why it is closed. He or she will do some minimal research. That is a good enough indication that the user is genuinely interested and genuinely wants an answer. A user who should be nurtured, who might become a valuable contributor in the foreseeable future.

My last observation concerns unregistered users to the site. To my consternation I have noted there seems to an increase of unregistered users on the site,  a great number of these "first time posters" disappear within the first hour or two *never* to return. Very often their questions are the very ones which users on EL&U complain most about. They are the FTPs who don't even look up a word in a dictionary before asking a question on spelling: [Real Estate or Real-Estate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196243/real-estate-or-real-estate) Moreover that unregistered user vanished after one hour, the user did not reply to any of the comments left by members. That user behaved  like a mosquito. A small question bite, and then buzzed off.

Another more recent example is this: [Fulfil vs. Fulfill](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196366/fulfil-vs-fulfill) That is a question which should go to the unanswered queue. If the OP wants to reopen his/her question then they go through the normal channels.

And while those two questions along with a multitude of similar ones are still visible on the front page, the good questions sink in a sludge of banality.

Why are those two questions (on September 14) still visible on the first fifty questions page? Why are those questions, along with dozen of others, cluttering the site? Put them  in "quarantine". If the OPs return, the questions remain. If after a week they haven't intervened or made any edits etc., delete the lot.

That's my little rant over

---

### Are "answers" in comments responsible for newcomers leaving the site after one hour?

I think, in part, they are. The number of newcomers who post a question to then disappear without trace is also due to receiving decent "answers" in comments. As these unregistered FTP tend to be non-native speakers, I believe, they are unaware of how the Q&A system works. Whereas users who have 100 rep will already be familiar with the Stack exchange model.

I'd like all of us to pay particular attention to newcomers who have seemingly vanished. Are there comments which could be misconstrued as answers? I would also strongly suggest to refrain from leaving such comments, especially to users who have 1 rep. They should be better informed that comments are often wild guesses which may or not be the answer they are looking for.

---

### The "Hit&Run" users (updated)

Here is yet another unanswered [off-topic question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198774/accadimic-english) posed by a "hit&run" or "first time poster". An unregistered user who will *not* return, comment, edit or participate under the same username again. As this appears to be somewhat a pattern, I'm thinking is there a way to check their IP addresses to see if *any* are repeating offenders?

Comment: I am hopeful (perhaps naively?) that once ELL graduates out of beta, and starts getting more SEO love, this question will be moot.  We've really got to find a way to raise awareness of that site as the best place to answer "basic" English questions (problem is, no one really likes to be told "your question is too basic, go sit at the kids' table").

Comment: @DanBron and if that's another year? If the mods were allowed to group the "on hold" questions together, move them to a different page, thereby providing the "on topic" questions greater visibility, wouldn't that already be an improvement?

Comment: @DanBron Nobody likes to be humiliated, true, but if after several comments of helpful advice has been freely given and the OP stubbornly ignores them. Well, frankly I don't care if their feelings do get hurt. It's one thing to see an OP who responds and edits a question, it's quite another who maintains a stony silence.

Comment: Oh, listen, I agree with your proposal and hope it gets implemented (one of those +1s is mine).  It's just that SE admins are a fairly conservative bunch, and in general the philosophy "be nicer to the newbies" has prevailed over "improve the signal:noise ratio" (witness the mess that is SO). And it's worth noting that snailboat said, on the "Make ELL a valid move target" question, that ELL is in the "graduation queue" already.

Comment: I hope you didn't interpret any of *my* comments as saying you're encouraging anonymous downvotes! That idea never entered this guy's head.

Comment: @DanBron I was anticipating those who might oppose my idea by advocating the use of downvotes.

Comment: K, just so we're clear, I like your idea and hope it gets implemented. But that said, I don't have anything more substantial to offer which would merit a formal answer.

Comment: The OPs I find contemptible are the ones who are happy enough to ask their ill-phrased, minimally-researched questions, have someone else clarify and reformat them, receive answers from multiple respondents who have often devoted considerable time and effort to researching and composing their replies, and who then bugger off without so much as upvoting or accepting an answer or even just posting a "thank you" comment under the better answers. That is not merely a case of those users being unfamiliar with the ELU model; it's a manifestation of their rampant self-centredness and bad manners.

Comment: @ErikKowal do we feel better now? :) But I do share your sentiment, it's something that has happened to everyone. But recently, good answers are not even upvoted. I sense an air of complacency, of "I can't be bothered any more to participate" especially true from the more seasoned users. I don't belong to that category, I'm still wet behind the ears :) Did you upvote my proposal? The more upvotes it receives the more "management" will stop and listen.

Comment: Yes, 'we' did upvote your proposal. However, having read many quite good suggestions for improvement on the meta site that have led nowhere, I am not particularly optimistic that 'management' is suddenly going to wake up now. But I'm willing to let them prove me wrong.  :)

Comment: @ErikKowal *Don't give up the fight*, someone once told me.

Comment: Is it 'declutter' or 'unclutter'? _ducks and runs_

Comment: @Mitch I quickly checked online before posting and saw both were legit, but I didn't spend much time pondering over details.

Comment: Mari, you didn't look it up on ELU?

Comment: @mitch Nope. Let me guess, one of the two is "wrong". But is it such a terrible thing to post? It's no big deal. But, you've forced me to look it up on ELU now. Bugger... Right, judging by the total absence of *declutter*, I have to infer it is "incorrect". But I like it! And I'm gonna keep it!

Comment: @Mitch your query inspired me to ask a question on EL&U : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196847/should-i-say-declutter-or-unclutter-my-desk No need for running or ducking. I'd be interested to hear a native AmEng  viewpoint.

Comment: @Mari-LouA With the new edit, I feel like this question now has 2 separate proposals, which makes it hard to evaluate. I personally agree with the first proposal, and disagree with the second.  For FTPs with basic questions, I actually like giving short, simple, *unexplained* answers in the comments, usually with a pointer to ELL or otherwise an indication of whatever inadequacy I perceive in the question. I feel it makes the site friendlier to newcomers without encouraging terrible questions, or leaving the database full of *completely* unanswered questions.

Comment: But by giving short unexplained answers to a newcomer who is unfamiliar with Stack Exchange, s/he  *might* believe the comment **is** the answer and so disappear, leaving the user who does post a detailed well-researched answer empty handed. Of course this doesn't always happen, if the answer is top notch people will notice and will naturally want to show their approval. But the OP, the person who asked the question? He or she is gone, and whether I or you like it or not, they don't come back.

Comment: @DanBron (cont'd) Haven't you noticed the drop in views recently? Unless a question hits the whatchamacallit "hot questions" queue, the number of views per question is very very low. Look at the first page, questions posted two hours ago, 25 views;   three hours ago, 32 views; four hours ago, 53 views. The users who answer are the sames one, over and over again. I'm not sure, I'm going to stay for much longer, unless the quality of questions rises (and pretty soon) or the number of visitors increase I feel that it's all a bit pointless... it's quite sad.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, huh, I never really looked at / tracked views before.  At first blush, a lot of the questions on the front page are kinda .. dull. Not due to formatting, but fundamental content.  I think because ESL students are finding this site instead of ELL. When there's an interesting question, or at least one with an intriguing title, views shoot right up (like your two recent ones).

Comment: @DanBron not really, that's not true. My jiffy question got 15 upvotes but hasn't touched the 300 visits. The Conyon Doyle one has 268 views. A pittance, if you think about it. And the accepted answer, I think was brilliant, I am really excited about emrys57's discovery. I think it's brill! And it's a shame that it's gone unnoticed. While a question about fishing is what? 2,000+ views. It's a "fun" question, but it's related to video games and coding. Not *really* about  English, is it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I think that's a deeper issue than getting clutter off the front page. My rep has x-tuple'd over the last month or so here, and I've noticed that an insignificant amount of that increase is due to answers I felt were interesting, well-researched, well-written, and even surprising. The vast majority of my rep has come from trivial answers to trivial questions. I think this is an artifact of the reality that people upvote things they can agree with, and obvious, widely-known things are easier to agree with, for more people with less thought. In other words, the votes are *cheap*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA (cont'd) For a concrete example of *that* problem, and how your (2nd) proposal is orthogonal to treating it: currently, my most upvoted answer is something I originally considered [a throwaway answer to a throwaway question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196097/word-for-a-software-bug-that-occurs-again-after-having-fixed-it/196099#196099), which I originally posted because on the previous few questions, people had encourage me to post my *comments as answers*, though they be trivial.

Comment: I fully agree about the *cheap votes*, but you ARE very good. An excellent "new" contributor along with Erik Kowall and a few others, whose names have slipped my mind.

Comment: @Mari-LouA (cont'd, final) Contrast that with a question I found interesting, difficult to answer, and [very rewarding to resolve](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/189291/55623). Trivial? 77 upvotes; Well-researched? 3 upvotes. *A difference of **256%** in favor of trivial*. (At first blush, the zonal/meridional question may not look well-researched, but trust me when I say I spent a long time looking for those words!)

Comment: What do you mean by ‘the "unanswered" page’? There is no “quarantine” view like what you describe. There is an [“unanswered” view](http://english.stackexchange.com/unanswered) (which can be filtered by tag and ordered in several ways), but it's a place to find questions that are in need of answers (or upvotes on an existing answer with non-positive score), quite the opposite of what you describe. The point of the “newest” view is to show all (non-deleted) questions, no ifs and buts.

Comment: @Gilles the [unanswered page](http://english.stackexchange.com/unanswered) exits, and I use the expression "quarantine" as a metaphor, a turn of speech. The newest page, in my opinion, would benefit if it was limited to displaying only questions which are not *put on hold* or *closed*. Many questions are "put on hold" but they *clutter* the first two or three pages. I know there is no quarantine, that's why I'm asking for one! My post is a request. Coincidentally many of these *on hold* questions are unanswered too.

Comment: @Gilles today there are only four "on hold" questions in the first 50 questions, two duplicates (which I argue should not be moved) that's not too bad, but on other days it can be 7 or 8 *on hold* questions and 3-5 duplicate questions, so why leave them on the newest page? Only users with enough rep can vote to reopen these questions, which they will see in their review queue in any case. My question is a proposal, there are too many posts that are off topic which should be automatically deleted after a week of non-activity. I am referring to those posts which are *on hold* AND unanswered.

Comment: MaryLou, I agree with almost every opinion and suggestion you posted.  If I had read it before, I'm not sure I would have posted my own question.  You posted it last year and not much has changed since then.  As for "hit and run" (or FTP's) I agree that answering the question in a comment is one of the reasons why they go away and never wait for an answer.  Most of them expect a quick answer and are not really interested in becoming a member.  However, what I have also seen a few times, is an arrogant comment, sometimes by high rep users. Not the kind of

Comment: comment where you say: "what research have you done?", "Where have you looked?"  or “Why don’t you look it up in a dictionary?”, but comments that may be offensive, such as “"You want a word meaning your countrymen are "monotonous"?  Well, your country ranks fifth in homicide rates. I would call your countrymen anything but monotonous."”  Of course that comment was removed minutes later, but that member took the trouble to find something depreciating about the FTP’s country  instead of helping him.  That type of comment surely scares quite a few prospective long-time users.

Comment: @Centaurus yes, of course. Courtesy, and manners must be extended to everyone, to newcomers and oldies such as ourselves. But some newcomers are incredibly naive and/or arrogant that they invite rudeness. Respect and politeness has to be reciprocal. Btw the "hit 'n' run" users, are called [**ask'n'run questioners**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209913/what-do-you-call-a-qa-user-who-posts-a-question-but-never-checks-back) I posted a question last year asking for the correct terminology :)

Answer (score 6):

This is [already happening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675). Quoting Shog9’s answer at MSE, the criteria are these:

> Automatic deletion of closed, abandoned questions for questions meeting the following criteria:
>
> - Closed more than 9 days ago
> - Not closed as a duplicate
> - Score <= 0
> - Not locked
> - No answers with a score > 0
> - No accepted answer
> - No pending reopen votes
> - No edits in the past 9 days

Running the [SEDE query for questions that are all of: 

**Closed
 scoring <= 0
 no accepted answers
 no answers scoring > 0
 no reopen votes
 no recent edits**](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/225187/closed-scoring-0-no-accepted-answers-or-answers-scoring-0-no-reopen-votes?deadline=9) 
for ELU at this moment yields 575 questions slated for summary deletion.

Comment: So there are 575 questions scheduled to be deleted, since when? Since April 2013? How often does this happen?

Comment: What about my suggestion to shift questions on hold immediately to the unanswered questions (quarantine) page?

Comment: @Mari-LouA That query seems to be pulling up duplicates. I’m not sure how to modify it to fix that. But if you look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days) unter the recently deleted list, you will see that the Community user deletes closed questions daily.

Comment: "9 days". As always, people working at SE expect everyone to visit the site almost as often as they do, which is absurd. It's perfectly natural for someone to come back once in a while.

Comment: @Lohoris I don't understand what you mean by "9 days"

Comment: @Mari-LouA I mean that's a very short time, but they don't realise it because they, as the admins, are used to come back to the site multiple times a day.