# Why was my question about improving this site deleted by "Community ♦"?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-posts

This is the deleted question:
https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6709/a-simple-proposal-to-encourage-people-to-ask-better-questions

Can it be re-opened?

Well, I didn't get much support or attention. I don't know if it is a reason to delete.

Comment: Try your luck at [Meta S.E](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), you will very likely get fast answers, and fast upvotes; or downvotes if this feature has already been suggested and rejected by the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an MSE post about [deletion of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

> 8. The system will automatically delete [unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

I didn't realise this applied to Meta posts, but I suppose there's no reason not to.

Your post was not locked, was at −1 and had no answers. The last comment on it was on March 27, so it was deleted after thirty days or thereabouts on April 25. It's "thereabouts" because deletions are done by a scheduled job.

Perhaps it was too specific for a question. That is, instead of a question "Would this fix this problem?" it seems more common to ask a question "What would fix this problem?" which allows a variety of answers. You could try adding your proposal as an answer to [a related question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6819/is-there-anything-we-can-do-to-get-fewer-off-topic-questions).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to re-open then? I can change the title of the question also.

Comment: @ermanen For questions that were deleted by vote, or by the actions of a mod, there's a way for users to vote-to-undelete. That's rare, but it happens. I'm not sure if it's possible to undelete a question which was automatically deleted for inactivity (i.e. by Community<>), though. It might be best to ask another question, and phrase it in a way which would attract more engagement. Even if the old one is revived, it's not clear that it would get any more attention than the last time around.

Comment: @ermanen I would suggest that the proposal you made is better added as an answer to the more general question.