# How would we like to format our keywords?

Tags: discussion, search

For a long time, the EL&U community has had a problem.  We have been unable to search for stop words ([common words that are not searchable](http://www.searchengineshowdown.com/defs/stop.html)), which is "[problematic since many of the questions on the site [are] about stop words](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/need-a-way-to-search-for-stop-words)."

Six months ago, the SE search engine introduced a feature that, if conscientiously implemented, would give us a workaround for not being able to search on stop words.

That feature is the ability to search for *any* text contained within code tags.

**Theoretically, the code tags could therefore be used to enclose stop words that should not be ignored by the search engine.**

Now, we have discouraged the use of code tags on the site, in part because they look ugly, and in part because blockquotes are really more suited to what we do here.

However, the argument has been made that ***keywords,*** i.e. the words we use to find the particular posts we are looking for, are essentially the "code" of our site.  In other words, we could use code tags around words in the posts (particularly around relevant stop words) in order to improve the efficiency of searching because stop words enclosed in code tags would no longer be ignored.

For example, right now, you cannot easily find the question "[What is the best way to explain how to choose between “its” and “it's”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-best-way-to-explain-how-to-choose-between-its-and-its)" using the site search engine because "its" and "it's" are stopwords.

If we insert code tags in the body—What is the best way to explain how to choose between `its` and `it's`?—the question becomes much easier to find because we can look for "its" directly.

So if we consider marking keywords with code tags, currently keywords would be formatted `thus`.  There exists the possibility that we can alter this formatting to something more appealing and site-specific.  The question is

**What is an acceptable, obvious, and standard method of marking keywords?**

Some suggestions have been

- Italics
- Italics plus underline
- Italics plus bold
- Italics plus dotted underline
- Small caps
- Small cap bold italics plus dotted underline plus green plus blink
- Leave it like it `already is` (and perhaps stick them at the bottom)
- Make them look like regular text

Text would be tagged like it is now, by the poster or the community as we decide that it is needed for the purposes of making the site more searchable.  It might have helped [this user](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81184/should-i-use-all-the-or-all-of-the) this morning, for instance.

What says the community?

Comment: I am leaning towards green blink. But would it be conspicuous enough without a moving pop-up?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "keywords".

Comment: 1.  Whose job will it be to decide what the keywords are? Is this something the mods will do, or is it up to the poster, or does the whole community get to kick in?    2. Are there alternatives to disfiguring the copy? Could we stick a keywords line at the bottom? Labeled something cheery like "Keywords:", or not. Then it wouldn't really matter what you did with them.

Comment: I don't understand this. What are "keywords", where/why would I find/use them, and why does it matter how they're displayed?

Comment: @Fumble The words we use to find the things we are looking for. This is problematic on this site because the search ignores stop words (like "its") which are things we might actually want to search for here; you might not ever use them if you don't search for stuff; because some people don't like the way code tags look and they leave the impression that we are talking about code when we're not.

Comment: @KitFox: Seems like an odd usage to me. Since the site indexer ignores "stop words" like *its*, I don't bother with them in my **search terms**. Unlike Google, SO searches don't seem to honour "quotated search strings", so I still don't see what you're getting at.

Comment: @Fumble The fact that the site indexer ignores stop words is *entirely the point*, and simply omitting them when one is searching for a question on the difference between "its" and "it's" is not going to yield very useful results.

Comment: I must be extra thick today. I *know* they don't work as search terms - but I don't know what you're proposing to do about that, or why it currently makes any difference how the site displays words that are no use to us anyway. No use at the moment, at least, and I don't see how that can change unless TPTB give us our own site-specific index & search facilities.

Comment: @Fumble Why do you think "its" versus "it's" is no use to us anyway? What about when someone is looking for a dupe?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, if I understand it correctly, TPTB are giving us (or rather, have given us) a tool that we can use to index our own content, and that indexing then appears in search results. So, it's site-specific index & search facilities, but via a workaround of sorts.

Comment: I for one still do not understand what you mean by keyword. Are you talking about displaying things in search results? Or are you talking about putting markup around stop words in the original text? or around _non_ stop words in the original text? Or what? Presumably, we don't want the original text of questions and answers to look any different at all, whether stop or non stop words. Or maybe you're saying we do? You want -all- stop words to be formatted differently? " `the` man `on` `the` bike " ? We're just trying to create a hack that will allow us to search on stop words? And look crappy?

Comment: @Mitch: you'd only mark a stop word as a keyword if it's, well, a key word, e.g. if you're talking about the pronunciation of `the`.

Comment: And the point is to make it not `look crappy`.

Comment: Oh, so essentially _quote_ everything in a special way that you want to search for as language text?

Comment: Some background: we have had a search parameter `code:` silently implemented for a while. While its purpose and intent remains for our programming oriented sites to help search for otherwise undiscoverable elements such as `++` and `-->`, I realized it could also avoid the usual issue of stop words (among other curations possible). So I, personally, stepped over here and brought word of it as a potential option to use, *if people were interested in using the syntax*. That's really the gist of it from the SE end - just one person who thought it might be nice if people liked it.

Comment: @GraceNote: OK. I misunderstood what the whole suggestion was about. You're saying that a feature was introduced silently a while back that allows you to search for anything, using the 'code:' tag,  within back quotes, even stop words (because they are not treated as stop words within those quotes). So this question is all about whether we at ELU want to display backquoted text different than usual? Is that all? (I was quite led astray by 'theoretically' as though it were a possible new feature on top of the old one.)

Comment: @Mitch Basically, yes - as a means to adapt using this *existing* search parameter, it is possible (though thus far unprecedented) to change the way code formatting is rendered, since there seems to be a pretty strong consensus that the current version is "butt ugly, especially in-line". Or, simpler, "If we adopt using code formatting now instead of pushing for different tools in the unknown future, how should it look?"

Comment: @GraceNote What words are exactly considered stop words, on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @kiam At the moment, our stop word list is mostly the [built-in list for Lucene](http://ankitjain.info/ankit/2009/05/27/lucene-search-ignore-word-list/) (what backs our search engine). We did add some words of our own, but for the most part, that list up there gives the general impression.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, there are about [70,800 questions](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&q=site:english.stackexchange.com/questions+%22the%22+-newest+-recently) with the word *the* in them, but `code:the` in the ELU search box returns only 327 results.  How do you account for that?

Comment: @jwpat7 try with [code:it](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=code%3ait). To me, it returned my own answer, which didn't contain `it`, but _it_, or _It_. Now I deleted my answer, so you should check with another answer.

Comment: @kiam First off, sorry about the language I had used earlier, it was not my intention to offend you by my word choice. Anyway, `code:it` will return every post on the site, actually, if you neglect to use quotation marks. This has been absent from statement in this posting, but let me reassert it: **the term for the code: search parameter must be enclosed in quotation marks**. Even if it may work for larger words without it, it's simpler to be consistent and apply them at all times.

Comment: @GraceNote I am simply pointing out that the result is not what the average user would expect; I am not saying what the result **must** be, in the same way I am not saying users **must not** use quoted strings. As for using a quoted string for `code:`, that is necessary in some cases, not in all cases. As for [code:and](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DA0DK.png) versus [code:"and"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hPUbW.png), I get the same results. Notice I used two different browsers, and in one case I am not logged-in.

Comment: @kiam I'm not questioning you, or even countering you. I'm just providing new instruction that was, as noted, absent from being mentioned prior.

Answer (score 3):

If keywords will be listed at the bottom of a post, then as StoneyB said, who cares how they're formatted?  The current behavior is fine.

If keywords will be embedded in running text -- that is, you're asking people to use <code> to flag keywords in the body of the post -- then you should not change the formatting at all.  Keywords are meta-information; you don't need to present that meta-information to readers. Cluttering up a paragraph with `monospaced` text, ***over-formatted*** text, <sub>tiny text</sub>, weirdly-colored text, etc makes it harder to read.  (Yeah yeah, I couldn't exactly implement all those examples right given the limited markup permitted here.)

Comment: Well, the formatting would be `monospaced` because in order for it to work, we'd have to use code tags, which currently put that formatting on it.

Comment: @KitFox, I read the question as suggesting CSS overrides for code (given that code can mark keywords).  Sorry if I misunderstood.  <code> with monospace in a line at the end is fine and seems easy for all involved; if the idea is to use <code> inline to mark keywords, I'd want to remove its styling.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly

- The SE search engine ignores a finite number of words—**stop words**—such as articles, particles, perhaps prepositions and copulae and so forth
- But in many cases these **stop words** themselves are the subject of our posts, and are precisely the **key words** an ELU user might employ in a search
- A cheap and easy workaround is to mark any **stop words** which would serve as  appropriate **key words** for the post with code tags, which override the 'ignore' directive and include the marked **stop words** in the search
- There is no need to mark any word which is not a **stop word**
- There is no need to mark any **stop word** more than once in any post

If these are all true, then the issues before the community are

1. Where shall **stop words** be marked with code tags be entered?—in the body of the post, or at some place apart, such as at the end?
2. Who shall be responsible for marking appropriate **stop words**?
3. How shall marked **stop words** be displayed?—with the
   existing formatting or with some other formatting peculiar to ELU?

My votes on these issues:

1. To avoid confusing the reader, marked words should be entered at the end of the post, with the label Andrew Leach offers, as below (with or without the blockquoting)
2. The poster should take responsibility for entering appropriate Additional Keywords; but like any other part of the post, they may be added to or subtracted from by community editors.
3. If the marked words aren't in the body, who cares? Leave it as it is, and don't create work for anybody.

> **Additional Keyword:** `KISS`

Comment: Yes, I was thinking we could add the words ad hoc to existing posts to make them easier to find.

Comment: Yes.  If the keywords are going to be in a block at the bottom, who cares?  If you're talking about using <code> inline in posts to signal keywords, that's a different matter.

Comment: I'd be happy with this, because it's an obvious way of using the additional search functionality without upsetting anything else (including tables, but the possible exception of RegDwight) *and* it means we can carry on squashing inline `code` in the text, which is ugly and unnecessary. I like the blockquote, too; it's rather like an extra row of tags.

Comment: However I do think that the grey background is Not A Good Thing. The background for `code` should be the same colour as tags currently are -- both because it looks better and keywords are also meta-data.

Comment: Except the way I see this being *most* useful is if you choose backticks to make a use/mention distinction, it will automagically cause your keywords to show up in search results -- no extra work required. And for that to be a viable option, the formatting needs to be Not Ugly.

Comment: @Martha I find *any* visible mark in the body copy which is not a part of my argument to be gratuitous, intrusive and distracting, regardless of whether it's ugly. I'd rather take three seconds to post the words at the end.

Comment: @StoneyB: if you're talking about words, rather than using them, then you kind of *have* to mark the words somehow, don't you? Compare "Do you need a that in the following sentence?" to "Do you need a `that` in the following sentence?" The former sounds nonsensical; the latter, in addition to clarifying your meaning, makes your question searchable even though the main point is a stop word, *without needing to add more text at the bottom*. The problem is, it's ugly. **This** is why we need to change the code formatting.

Comment: @Martha  Suppose I need to mark "that"  "yon" "haggis" and "Scots" as terms under discussion -- why should I be constrained either to use a different marker for "that" than for the others or to mark them all as 'code'? What am I telling my reader? If I enter "that" explicitly as a keyword at the end, I'm free to use whatever marker seems appropriate in the body.

Comment: @StoneyB: nobody's preventing you from adding a keyword section at the end, if that's the way you prefer to work. My point is, that's *not* how *I* prefer to work, and for my purposes, the formatting applied by backticks **does** matter. I'm not constraining you; you're constraining me.

Comment: @Marthaª  OK, I'll buy that

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of those who never uses `code` markup on ELU because (1) frankly, it looks ugly, and (2) it's pretty well-ingrained on the web that *"a bit of typewriter font in the middle of proportional-spaced text"* is synonymous with computer code, and is thus not really appropriate on ELU. Apparently, this means that I've been unknowingly disabling the search functions every time I've used bold or italics or quotes to make a use-mention distinction.

So, if we are to start using code markup to highlight keywords, the formatting needs to ***not*** scream "I'm computer code", and the first step to that is to use a proportional font, not a monospaced one. It also needs to be differentiated from the existing bold and italic formatting, which pretty much means using color in some manner.

Another consideration is that there are people who *have* used the code markup on this site, and at least some of them doubtless used it because they *wanted* their text to look like typewriter-on-gray. So we don't want to totally change the appearance of this text; blinking green is Right Out<sup>TM</sup>.

Thus, the best formatting option in my opinion would be to use exactly **the same font as the rest of ELU**, but **with a gray background** like the existing `code` formatting.

---

Edit: I took a look at the html that results from the two types of 'code' markup, and my concerns re:<pre> appear unfounded. Backticks (inline code) apply <code> tags *only*. Four-space indents (block-level code) apply *both* <pre> and <code>. This means that it should be easy to achieve the best of both worlds: use <code> to apply a background color only, *without changing the font family*, and use <pre> to apply the whitespace preservation as well as the monospaced font family. This would mean that people could continue to use code blocks for tabular data, while inline highlights would be much less ugly.

---

I think relegating keywords to *only* a section at the end of a post is bad idea. If people want to add a keyword section like that to the end of their posts, that's all well and good, but *I* don't like to work that much. The way I see it, this searching-in-code business would be most useful if it Just Worked, without any extra effort on anybody's part. And the way that can happen is if we switched to using backticks to mark words that we mention: instead of

> Should the following use *that* or *which*?

we'd have

> Should the following use `that` or `which`?

Both serve the purpose of highlighting the words that are important to the question, but only the latter is returned in search results.

(We'd still need to train people not to use code formatting in lieu of blockquotes; most of the results currently returned by "code:[stop word]" searches are irrelevant posts where somebody used code blocks instead of blockquotes.)

Comment: The idea (as I understand it) is that it's intended here for additional code **words** which are used in a similar way to the existing tags. And it would only be needed for "stop" words. So for example at the end of your post there could be **Additional keyword: `pre`**

Comment: Code tags *are* used on EL&U for presenting tabular data. The monospaced font, and the preservation of whitespace, are important factors there.

Comment: If you specify a background color you must also specify a text color.  It's an accessibility issue.

Comment: @Andrew: I like your idea of including an "Additional keyword:" prenote.  (I think what you wrote, at the bottom of a question, would be much preferable to **`pre`** sitting all by its lonesome.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not **treat anything already between quotes as 'searchable'**? That is, in the tokenizer throw out stop words as usual *except* tokenize everything that is already quoted: single, double, italic, bold, code, whatever.

That way, there is no laborious editing that needs to be done by anybody by hand, no need to educate people (which will be long hard and won't benefit the writer), no annoying UI changes. There might need to be a retokenizing of all posts so far, but that is something for the developers to run once.

It seems that the OP is not about a theoretical, to-be-developed feature, but just describing an existing feature (no development at SE needed at all) that allows literal searching on text between backquotes.

My suggestion here is that when analyzing/tokenizing is done, in the character class of 'code delimiters' which currently is

> [`],

the developers simply change it to

> [`"'].

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not on the table.  The workaround is specific to existing functionality, which is "stuff between code tags."

Comment: but code tags are just another kind of quote. instead of "stuff between code tags" just do "stuff between quotes".

Comment: My original intent was to pitch the prospect and get a feel for what people thought of leveraging existing functionality - I did in fact expect a fair amount of "no" based on the current aesthetic. I cannot, at the moment, do anything about queueing up a new search parameter, no matter how simple it is in implementation and execution.

Comment: I think the esthetic is irrelevant (or at best a distraction). This is all just education: "If you search with 'code:' then you can find things within backquotes literally (stopwords and punctuation and all). So if you want, start backquoting stuff to allow it to get searched.". Is that the gist of the situation? I.e. this is not a 'hack' or 'workaround' but really, "this is how to do it now." Just that we'd have to start quoting things with backquotes for the benefit of future generations.

Comment: KitFox, @GraceNote: if I have it correctly, my answer is actually a new feature request for searching rather than a reply to the OP about CSS styling. Though my answer is thus an indirection, I'll let it stay since I think it responds to the actual need better.

Comment: Kinda sorta? It's not just backquotes - using the 4 space indentation to activate markdown code formatting also works (and is largely what other sites who use it more primarily do it). This isn't meant as a "This is how to do it now", rather "This is how you *might* do it now, if you choose it." Expanding the function of the search parameter to hit different formats, or to hit things which are not formatted at all (double quotes do not apply any special formatting, after all) would indeed be a separate feature request.

Answer (score -1):

KitFox's question includes several issues that should be discussed in separate meta questions, as noted below; but first, let me suggest we say *search-terms* (or the gross *searchable-terms*, etc.) rather than *keywords*, as the latter is confusingly close to the question-tags concept.

Issues that deserve well-couched questions of their own:

> • Whether code-formatting (backtick-delimited or four-space-indented) should be co-opted to mark search-terms
>   • Visual appearance of user-marked search-terms [which, if OP formatting is the guide, is the main thrust of OP]
>   • Whether user-marking of search-terms can succeed
>   • What long-term changes should be made in the SE search engine or search box to better deal with ELU-relevant searching

Regarding that fourth issue, what would be useful to me for searching ELU would be having the top-of-page search box do a Google search instead of an SE search.  Conceivably, a user-selected formula could specify a search engine, SE, Google, Bing, etc., but for simplicity let's suppose the user's search text were tacked on at the end of `site:english.stackexchange.com/questions` and shipped to Google, as is done in the Google box on the [search-tips-for-better-search-results](https://english.stackexchange.com/search) webpage.  I'd prefer to have `-newest -recently` also tacked on, as in the following three searches:

> • for ["“its” and “it's”"](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&q=site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+++-newest+-recently&oq=site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+++-newest+-recently&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.12...214217.214217.0.218170.1.1.0.0.0.0.609.609.5-1.1.0.s6pAVIT0uzI#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:english.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+%22%E2%80%9Cits%E2%80%9D+and+%E2%80%9Cit%27s%E2%80%9D%22++-newest+-recently&oq=site:english.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+%22%E2%80%9Cits%E2%80%9D+and+%E2%80%9Cit%27s%E2%80%9D%22++-newest+-recently&gs_l=serp.12...12568.12568.2.23222.1.1.0.0.0.0.122.122.0j1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1j2.72-Gnbr5V4w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=a6643b7549a4f72d&biw=1003&bih=579), about 41 results
>   • for ["“its” and “its”"](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&q=site:english.stackexchange.com/questions+%22%E2%80%9Cits%E2%80%9D+and+%E2%80%9Cit%27s%E2%80%9D%22+-newest+-recently#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:english.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+%22%E2%80%9Cits%E2%80%9D+and+%E2%80%9Cits%E2%80%9D%22+-newest+-recently&oq=site:english.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+%22%E2%80%9Cits%E2%80%9D+and+%E2%80%9Cits%E2%80%9D%22+-newest+-recently&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.1.7717763.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.u6PA5zww4Xc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=a6643b7549a4f72d&biw=1003&bih=579), about 2 results
>   • for ["“it's” and “its”"](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:english.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+%22%E2%80%9Cit%27s%E2%80%9D+and+%E2%80%9Cits%E2%80%9D%22+-newest+-recently&oq=site:english.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+%22%E2%80%9Cit%27s%E2%80%9D+and+%E2%80%9Cits%E2%80%9D%22+-newest+-recently&gs_l=hp.12...1894.5545.0.6967.2.2.0.0.0.0.149.292.0j2.2.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.2j1.4mBNb7P-4XU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=a6643b7549a4f72d&biw=1003&bih=579), about 4 results

Regarding that search-tips page, I should mention three problems:

> • The `[tag] [another-tag] apples oranges` example is unclear.
>   • The `code:` prefix is not mentioned anywhere on the page.
>   • The “Advanced Super Ninja Search Options” section should instead be called “Ninja-in-Training Search Options”.