# Search for common words

Tags: discussion, search

I have a question that must have been asked here many times. The question is about using "it is" versus "this is".
Attempted to search for `it is` and `this is`, with and without quotes, and the search returned no results.

I realize SE engine is filtering common words, and that's fine. What is really frustrating is that using quotes does not help either.
See also: [Need a way to search for stop words](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/need-a-way-to-search-for-stop-words)

Google returns 12,700 results for `site:english.stackexchange.com/questions "it is" +"this is"`

What are my options?

Comment: I think we only had [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52495/it-vs-this), which got closed as gen-ref, but only after getting an answer that might help you.

Comment: @RegDwighт Thanks for the link; this is exactly what I was looking for. Nevertheless, what about search? Grammar constructs are large part of the language; excluding them by the search engine seems to be frustrating.

Comment: There's just been a discussion here of a possible [**workaround**](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/how-would-we-like-to-format-our-keywords). Unhappily, it's not a retrospective solution, but something which questioners/editors could be encouraged to implement going forward. [**This**](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/37/cant-search-for-a-question-about-that-and-which) suggests that for the time being going through Google is your best bet.