# Users should be marked as native speakers if they are

Tags: feature-request, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show native language with the answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/show-native-language-with-the-answer)
>   [Stack sites must support primary and secondary language when defining user profile](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/stack-sites-must-support-primary-and-secondary-language-when-defining-user-profil)

When accepting advice on English language use, it would be good to know whether the responder is a native speaker or not. One could set this information up in his profile and it would be displayed near the user's icon.